# same iframe load with other page from iframe jquery event

Tags: html, jsp, iframe, jquery

```
   <iframe id="iframe"  style=" width:100%; height:500px" src="other.jsp"  frameborder="0"  name="myone">
<html>
<head>
<script>
 $(function() {
                    $("#adduser1").click(function() {    
                        alert("hiiii");                 
                        $('#iframe').attr('src', 'adduser.jsp');
                    }); 
                });
</script>
</head>
<body>
            <input type="button" name="AddUser" id="adduser1" value="AddUser"/> 
</body>
</html>   
    </iframe>
```

here i want to load same iframe (its already loaded with other.jsp ) with other jsp adduser.jsp on triggering of  inside event of same iframe 
its alerting  with 'hiiii' but not loading with jsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load the iframe from a button which itself is inside the iframe, it will never work that way. You should use `window.location` for this

```
$(function() {
    $("#adduser1").click(function() {    

        window.location = 'adduser.jsp'
    }); 
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'adduser.jsp');
```

inside the self iframe. Use

```
window.location = 'adduser.jsp'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it should work and it works for me.

The constraint may be the path of the file.. If that is not the case.

Please try to reload the your iframe.

```
//Reload iframe
$('#iframe').attr('src', $('#iframe').attr('src'));
```

Just try this... this may help you!!

[**DEMO...**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwzc9/63/)

Comment: It is working for you because in your code button is outside the iframe but in question it is inside the iframe. You are loading iFrame from outside that is why it works for you.